# Como conseguir guardar las coordenadas del cuerpo en un archivo.txt en Visual Studio,C#

Tags: c#

Muy buenas, estoy intentando guardar en un archivo.txt las coordenadas que me proporciona Kinect de los diferentes Joints del cuerpo en Visual Studio. Pero como se trata de un array de tipo object no me deja pasar a string mediante la siguiente forma:
Esta seria la nueva parte implementada

```
                        //Mano Derecha
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightX = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightY = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightZ = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Z;


                        //ManoIzquierda
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftZ = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z;


                        //Cabeza 
                        VariablesGlobales.HeadX = body.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.HeadY = body.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.HeadZ = body.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Z;


                        // Parte central Torso
                        VariablesGlobales.SpineMidX = body.Joints[JointType.SpineMid].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.SpineMidY = body.Joints[JointType.SpineMid].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.SpineMidZ = body.Joints[JointType.SpineMid].Position.Z;


                        // Una de las soluciones es hacer un array para cada joint, como ultima opcion

                        DispatcherTimer dispatcher = new DispatcherTimer();
                        // Intervalo de tiempo de 1 segundo

                        dispatcher.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                        dispatcher.Tick += (s, a) =>
                         {
                             //MiArray[n] = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
                             // Estoy guardando toda la informacion necesaria de los 25 joints del body, es decir TODO EL BODY
                             MiArray[n] = body;
                             m = 0;
                             using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"prueba.txt",true))
                             {

                                 sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX);
                                 sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY);


                             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar debes tener el tipo real de tu objeto de manera que puedas accederlo. Sería muy útil que nos dieras más información del problema con código de ejemplo y/o alguna captura del error o del problema.

Actualmente no tengo VS disponible, pero te puedo decir que hay una mejor manera de hacer las cosas para escribir estos valores. Primero, debes asegurarte de que `VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX` sea un `float`, u otro tipo de valor base que puedas imprimir de manera cruda sin que sea una clase que cuando le haces `.ToString()` no retorna sino el tipo de objeto (`[System.Object]` o algo similar) sino un valor, por ejemplo `100.45`.

Para escribir deberías usar un Stream, que capaz te ayude a resolver el problema:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("prueba.txt", true)) {
    sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX);
    sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY);
    sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandRightX);
    sw.WriteLine(VariablesGlobales.HandRightY);
}
```

Debes conocer todas las propiedades de tu objeto para escribir los valores linea por linea. Si no las conoces debes usar Reflection. En cuanto al bucle no tengo mucha idea, asumo que en tu programa debes estar constantemente obteniendo un evento o haciendo un bucle con un `Timer` o similar para ver los nuevos valores. En ese bucle o rutina es que deberias escribir en tu archivo.

Esto debería ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: vale , ahora realizar un nuevo post :)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59217/discussion-on-answer-by-darkguy-como-conseguir-guardar-las-coordenadas-del-cuerp).